# What is automatic flushing in MATLAB's fopen function?

Tags: matlab, io, fopen

In `fopen` properties we can set 'W' and 'A' for `without automatic flushing` option. What is difference between these and using `automatic flushing` (default option)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When automatic flushing is on, matlab will effectively write **to disk** after any call to `fwrite` even if writing very small chunk of data.

When disabling automatic flushing, matlab only writes to **internal memory buffer** and flushes everything to disk only when calling `fclose` *(or when buffer is full)*. This may improve performances as less access to disk are required for writing operations.

Comment: Beat me to it.  Also, more details on performance can be found on this [Undocumented Matlab post](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/improving-fwrite-performance).